# Defining poisson distribution in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

I have this OR model in GAMS and i need to define a parameters which has poisson distribution, my code is:

```
Scalar Landa 'mean for poisson distribution' /3/;
Parameter L;
L=Poisson;
```

I get the error $140 which means unknown symbol
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define those variables in the `emp.info` file.

Add the following to you your GAMS code:

```
Scalar Landa 'mean for poisson distribution' /3/;
file emp / '%emp.info%' /; put emp '* problem %gams.i%'/;
$onput
randvar L poisson Landa
$offput
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I'm trying to use the random variable L in the rest of my code but i get the unknown symbol error for it.

Comment: BTW, you still need `paramenter L;` Do you have minimal example code for the error?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Scalar Landa 'mean for poisson distribution' /3/;
Parameter L;
L=E=Poisson;
```

Hope it helps!